# Yii2 GridView - use range DatePicker

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2

Is there a way to make two fields for picking dates in the **GridView** usign **DatePicke**. I need **dateFrom** and **dateTo** fields for a single atribute.

This is my current code:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'created_at',
    'label'     => 'Date Added',
    'value'     => 'created_at',
    'filter'    => \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget([
        'model'=>$searchModel,
        'dateFormat' => 'MM-dd-yyyy',
        'attribute'=>'dateFrom',                                
        'options'    => [
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ],

        ]),
    'format'    => ['date', 'php:m-d-Y, H:s']
]
```

Comment: I think you have to create two new attributes in your model and combine them on save.

Comment: Refer: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker#markup-range

Comment: This topic also should helps http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/55966-yii2-date-range/

Answer (score 1):

This will surely help you. You have to make following changes in GridView:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'created',
    'value' => 'created',
    'filter' => DateRangePicker::widget([
        'model' => $searchModel,
        'attribute'=>'created',
        'convertFormat'=>true,
        'pluginOptions'=>[
            'locale'=>[
                'format'=>'Y-m-d',
                'separator' => 'to',
            ]
        ]
    ])
],
```

You have to make following customization in Model Search Method:

```
$strCondition = '';
if (!empty($params['ModelSearch']['created'])) {
    $arrExplodeRange = explode('to', $params['ModelSearch']['created']);
    $strCondition = "created BETWEEN '". $arrExplodeRange[0] . "' AND '" . $arrExplodeRange[1] . "'";
}

$query = Category::find()->where($strCondition);
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```

Comment: Which library are you using for DateRangePicker?